# Simple IR Receiver code

Tags: ir

Can I know a code for simple IR receiver. I using external trasmitter, and when the receiver (on arduino board) get the input (detect signal from transmitter), LED will be HIGH.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. I suggest you ask a more specific question. There are plenty of examples of code that detects IR codes. It would be simple to turn an LED on if a certain code was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a library that might be able to help you out: https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib/. Also a specific example of controlling a server from a sony remote control. https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib/blob/master/examples/IRservo/IRservo.ino

I am slightly confused on what you mean 'get input'. So I am assuming an input from a button. Here is some pseudo code compiled from the IRservo example that might point you in the right direction.

```
#include <IRLib.h>

#define MY_PROTOCOL SONY
#define BUTTON_0 0x90bca  //LED ON
#define BUTTON_1 0x00bca  //LED OFF

#define LED_PIN 13 //Pin to LED

IRrecv My_Receiver(11);//Receive on pin 11
IRdecode My_Decoder;

void setup() { //Code to run once
  My_Receiver.No_Output();//Turn off any unused IR LED output circuit
  My_Receiver.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT); //Set LED 13 to out
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); //Start off in the off position
}

void loop() { //Code that runs forever
    if (My_Receiver.GetResults(&My_Decoder)) {
       My_Decoder.decode(); //Convert the values into types
       if(My_Decoder.decode_type==MY_PROTOCOL) { // Match the controller
          switch(My_Decoder.value) {
            case BUTTON_0:      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); break; //Turn the LED on
            case BUTTON_1:      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); break; //Turn the LED off
          }
       }
     My_Receiver.resume(); //Wait for next input
    }
}
```

This should theoretically work, but has never been tested. Now if you are just wanting any result to turn on the LED you might be able to do this

```
void loop() { //Code that runs forever
    if (My_Receiver.GetResults(&My_Decoder)) {
        My_Decoder.decode();
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); //Turn the LED on
    }
    My_Receiver.resume(); //Wait for next input
}
```

**Edit:**

A sample from getting text (Different library) from the receiver and printing it to the Serial Monitor. Link to library: https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

```
    #include <IRremote.h> //Link: https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

#define IR_PIN = 11; //The data pin to the IR recv
#define LED_DATA = 13; //Either the builtin LED or plug one in

IRrecv irrecv(IR_PIN); //Start recv obj
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start Serial at 9600 baud
  pinMode(LED_DATA, OUTPUT); //Set LED pin to out
  digitalWrite(LED_DATA, LOW); //Start recv data view pin in low
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    //We have recieved something... lets print it and turn on the LED
    digitalWrite(LED_DATA, HIGH);
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX); //Send line in ascii hex format
    delay(200); //Make the LED visible
    digitalWrite(LED_DATA, LOW); //Turn off data led
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

**Edit #2**

Since an image has been provided I believe this is what you want. To turn the ir data into a visible light... To do that is a little more tricky in just doing code. Here's an example that doesn't require any external libraries and will do what you want.

```
    #include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

#define TIMER_RESET  TCNT1 = 0
#define SAMPLE_SIZE  64
#defome LED_PIN 13

int IRpin = 2;
unsigned int TimerValue[SAMPLE_SIZE];
char direction[SAMPLE_SIZE];
byte change_count;
long time;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Analyze IR Remote");
  TCCR1A = 0x00;          // COM1A1=0, COM1A0=0 => Disconnect Pin OC1 from Timer/Counter 1 -- PWM11=0,PWM10=0 => PWM Operation disabled
  // ICNC1=0 => Capture Noise Canceler disabled -- ICES1=0 => Input Capture Edge Select (not used) -- CTC1=0 => Clear Timer/Counter 1 on Compare/Match
  // CS12=0 CS11=1 CS10=1 => Set prescaler to clock/64
  TCCR1B = 0x03;          // 16MHz clock with prescaler means TCNT1 increments every 4uS
  // ICIE1=0 => Timer/Counter 1, Input Capture Interrupt Enable -- OCIE1A=0 => Output Compare A Match Interrupt Enable -- OCIE1B=0 => Output Compare B Match Interrupt Enable
  // TOIE1=0 => Timer 1 Overflow Interrupt Enable
  TIMSK1 = 0x00;
  pinMode(IRpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Waiting...");
  change_count = 0;
  while(digitalRead(IRpin) == HIGH) {}
  TIMER_RESET;
  TimerValue[change_count] = TCNT1;
  direction[change_count++] = '0';
  while (change_count < SAMPLE_SIZE) {
    if (direction[change_count-1] == '0') {
      while(digitalRead(IRpin) == LOW) {}
      TimerValue[change_count] = TCNT1;
      direction[change_count++] = '1';
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    } else {
      while(digitalRead(IRpin) == HIGH) {}
      TimerValue[change_count] = TCNT1;
      direction[change_count++] = '0';
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Bit stream detected!");
  change_count = 0;
  time = (long) TimerValue[change_count] * 4;
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW)
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(direction[change_count++]);
  while (change_count < SAMPLE_SIZE) {
    time = (long) TimerValue[change_count] * 4;
    Serial.print(time);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(direction[change_count-1]);
    Serial.print(time);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(direction[change_count++]);
  }
  Serial.println("Bit stream end!");
  delay(2000);
}
```

If you want a non code example check out the answer below. It is a great solution. Without needing any arduino.

best regards, David

Comment: I mean "get the input" is receiver get signal from transmitter

Comment: I've added the new sample with getting data and printing it, and a library that seems slightly easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want code.  However your question is how to light up an LED when an external remote control is transmitting.  This can be done with the following hardware:

Many ASK sensors integrate an IR photo sensor, AGC & PLL into a 3 pin package that has an appearance of a transistor.  Supply power and get back a signal when an ASK IR transmitter is detected.  Check the current capabilities of the ASK receiver, you might have to add a transistor to drive an LED.  No Arduino needed for detection.

Here is an example found on the web:

[image]